# Scatter plot: getting ValueError (x and y must be the same size)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to do a scatter plot for my linear regression model. Here is the code that I tried, but it raises `ValueError: x and y must be the same size`.

```py
plt.scatter(X_test, y_test,  color='gray')
plt.plot(X_test, y_pred, color='red', linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

When I check the shape of my X_test, y_test, and y_pred the shape is as follows:

```py
X_test.shape
(355, 2)

y_test.shape
(355,)

y_pred.shape
(355,)
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your X_test has shape (355, 2) while y_test is (355,), so that's different shapes and sizes. I'm guessing your model input is 2D, and a scatterplot takes two 1D arrays to determine the position of the bubbles

I can think of 2 things you could do:

1- Plot the two inputs vs the prediction separetly:

To do this we flatten the input and get every other element starting from the first and second elements respectively

```
flat = X_test.flatten()
first_input = flat[::2]
second_input = flat[1::2]

plt.scatter(first_input, y_pred,  color='gray')
plt.plot(first_input, y_test, color='red', linewidth=2)
plt.show()

plt.scatter(second_input, y_pred,  color='gray')
plt.plot(second_input, y_test, color='red', linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

2- Plot the precision in the color, with the axis being the inputs for which you would need to create an array for the color

```
precision = y_pred == y_test
colors = ["blue" if x else "red" for x in precision]
```

What this is doing is first comparing each element of the prediction with the one in the test (this can be done thanks to them being numpy arrays)
Then it just creates a list where "red" is put for failed predictions and "blue" for right ones using list comprehension
And then just pass it to the color keyword:

```
plt.scatter(first_input, second_input,  color=colors)
plt.show()
```